# Having a checkboxes mark checkboxes recursively

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following function to group toggle checkboxes.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function toggle(source, wild_name) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(wild_name);
  for(var i in checkboxes)
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
</script>
```

So, when I click a checkbox which is defined as:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggle(this, 'tweak_os')" name="toggle_tweak_os"> Toggle All
```

It checks any checkbox named "tweak_os." But I'm trying to make this so that if a checkbox calls the function which checks another checkbox, the same function should be executed. In the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggle(this, 'toggle_tweak_os')" name="toggler">
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggle(this, 'tweak_os')" name="toggle_tweak_os">
<input type=checkbox id=tweak_os_1 name=tweak_os value=tweak_os_1>
```

I want the last checkbox called "tweak_os" to be checked when the first checkbox named "toggler" is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try triggering the checkbox's `onchange` function if it exist,

```
if (checkboxes[i].onchange) checkboxes[i].onchange();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wDBxb/

```
function toggle(source, wild_name) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(wild_name);
    for (var i in checkboxes) {
       checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
       if (checkboxes[i].onchange) checkboxes[i].onchange();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first checkbox change cause the selection of second but not third as the change of not second checkbox is not fired when changed with code. You need to fire the change event of the checkboxes with code as well if it is defined.

```
function toggle(source, wild_name) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(wild_name);
    for (var i in checkboxes) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        if (typeof checkboxes[i].onchange == "function") {
            checkboxes[i].onchange();
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What field does getElementsByName() look for?